# Golang OpenGL Build Constraints

Tags: go, opengl, build, constraints

I have spent the last few moths learning Golang and OpenGL.

I decided to try compiling my program for other platforms to see if my application would run fine.

My host operating system is **Windows 10** with the build architecture set to **amd64**.

My application compiles and runs without issue on my system '`Windows`', but when I try ti build for **Linux** or **Mac** I get the following issue:

```
GOHOSTOS=windows
GOHOSTARCH=amd64
GOOS=darwin
...

package main
        imports github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.5-core/gl: build constraints exclude all Go files in D:\Users\me\Documents\Programming\Project\src\github.com\go-gl\gl\v4.5-core\gl
```

The `go-gl` package can be found [here](https://github.com/go-gl/gl).

This is my **Mac** build script `build_macos.bat`:

```
echo off
cls
cd ..
set GOOS=darwin
set GOARCH=amd64
go env
go build -o bin/main.osx main
PAUSE
```

I am new to build constraints, so if anyone could help me resolve my issue it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

- `go-gl` version used: `4.5-core`.
- `golang` version used: `go version go1.16.4 windows/amd64`.

Comment: opengl bindings needs `cgo`, but cross compile disable `cgo` by default. You need to `set CGO_ENABLED=1`, and a c cross compiler (from windows to mac and linux, which is not as common for the reverse), and `set CC=somepath` and `set CXX=somepath`.

Comment: Thanks, setting `CGO_ENABLED=1` allowed me to compile for linux. Using `WSL` I was able to compile my application for linux.